# How do you add a new object to an existing JSON object in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, json, sql-update, mariadb

I have a JSON field with an object in it that contains multiple sub objects. The table looks like this:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|store_num|                           fruit_stock                          |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| AL258   | '{"fruits":{"apple":67,"banana":91,"plum":53}}'                |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| OR419   | '{"fruits":{"apple":109,"banana":44,"plum":98}}'               |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to add an object {"mango":45} to the "AL258" store using prepared statement. I came accross some issues doing this. First was adding an object to another object was not as straight forward as I thought it would be. It turns out I had to create the mango object using the JSON_OBJECT() funtion to start with so:

```
JSON_OBJECT("mango", 45)

'{"mango":45}'
```

I then had to get the contents of the "fruits" object so I had to use the JSON_QUERY() function for that:

```
JSON_QUERY(fruit_stock, '$.fruits')

'{"apple":67, "banana":91, "plum":53}'
```

Then had to merge the new mango object and the contents of the fruits object. Since I want to replace the field I'm inserting if it already exists I needed to use the JSON_MERGE_PATCH() function:

```
JSON_MERGE_PATCH(
    JSON_QUERY(fruit_stock, '$.fruits'),  -- the contents of fruit_stock: '{"apple":67,"banana":91,"plum":53}'
    JSON_OBJECT("mango", 45)              -- the new mango object: '{"mango":45}'
)
```

Now that I have the naked object fields '{"apple":67, "banana":91, "plum":53}', and '{"mango":45}' I needed to combine them into the "fruits" object. To do this I needed to create an entirely new "fruits" object using the JSON_OBJECT() function:

```
JSON_OBJECT(
    'fruits',                                 -- the new fruits object
    JSON_MERGE_PATCH(                         -- the contents of fruit_stock
        JSON_QUERY(fruit_stock, '$.fruits'),  -- the new mango object
        JSON_OBJECT("mango", 45)
    )
)

'{"fruits":{"apple":67, "banana":91, "plum":53, "mango":45}}'
```

Adding in a WHERE clause to select the store...

```
UPDATE store_table SET fruit_stock = 
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'fruits', 
        JSON_MERGE_PATCH(
            JSON_QUERY(fruit_stock, '$.fruits'), 
            JSON_OBJECT("mango", 45)
        )
    ) 
WHERE HEX(store) = 'AL258';
```

Results in the following table:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|store_num|                           fruit_stock                          |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| AL258   | '{"fruits":{"apple":67,"banana":91,"plum":53,"mango":45}}'     |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| OR419   | '{"fruits":{"apple":109,"banana":44,"plum":98}}'               |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My question: Is this the best way to do this, or is there a more efficient and/or readable option using MariaDB?

Comment: storing JSON strings in relational databases is absolutely senseless in my eyes

Comment: JSON is handy for a collection of miscellany _that you don't need to reach into_.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the similar syntax as the existing jsons for the values to be added by using `JSON_MERGE_PATCH()` function :

```
UPDATE store_table 
   SET fruit_stock = JSON_MERGE_PATCH(fruit_stock, '{"fruits":{"mango": 45}}') 
 WHERE store_num = 'AL258';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6295c3fc45793cd29011bfdb6b6fa7b2)</kbd>